# How to write a teradata SQL query case condition to check by ID and it's start date

Tags: teradata

There are same IDs in multiple records with different startdate spans.

I need to write a teradata sql case condition to check by ID and it's start date.
In the case condition, I need to check two conditions: if the ID has a startdate as current month and it doesn't have a startdate span in last three months then "yes it's a new member" else "not a new member".

Just FYI: below activerecord field is if the ID has a start date of current month it is shown as yes.

Example the table data is as below:

```
ID   startdate name.  activerecord 
101 03-01-2023 Lee     yes
101 02-01-2023 Lee     No
101 12-01-2022 Lee     No
102 03-01-2023 Mark.   yes
102 08-01-2022 Mark     No
102 07-01-2022 Mark.    No
```

I need the answer as below:

```
ID  startdate name  activerecord flag
101 03-01-2023 Lee   yes          No
101 02-01-2023 Lee   No.          No
101 12-01-2022 Lee   No.          No 
102 03-01-2023 Mark  Yes.         Yes
102 08-01-2022 Mark  No.          No
102 07-01-2022 Mark  No           No
```

Here 101 ID has a startdate as current month and  also has a start date span in last three months so this member is not a new member then print as 'No'.
102 ID has a startdate as current month but it doesn't have a date span in last three months so I need to consider this as a new member so print 'Yes'

I couldn't do this at all.

Comment: Seems you want something like `CASE WHEN activerecord='yes' and lag(startdate,1,date'1900-01-01') over (partition by ID order by startdate) < add_months(startdate, -3) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as flag`

Comment: Thank you so much Fred for your quick response. Could you please explain the above case condition you have written?

Comment: LAG is used to obtain the most recent startdate for an ID prior to the current row, and if there is no prior row for this ID then the 1900-01-01 date is returned (instead of NULL). Then it compares that date with a date that is 3 months prior to the date in the current row.

Comment: Hi Fred, I have a small change in my question. Should I update the existing question or create a new one and let you know?